# AngularJS, PHP form works fine on my own server. inserts blank rows into database on Godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I changed the database credentials to match my database, and my user has all privileges. Everything works fine on my own server with Apache and PHPMyadmin. I don't know what to do next.

App.js

```
  var myapp = angular.module('app', []);
  myapp.controller('submitctrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.insertdata=function(){
      $http.post("insert.php", {
        'FirstName':$scope.FirstName,
        'LastName':$scope.LastName,
        'Relation':$scope.Relation,
        'Recommendation':$scope.Recommendation,
        'FundManagementAbility':$scope.FundManagementAbility,
        'MentoringAbility':$scope.MentoringAbility,
        'OrganizationAbility':$scope.OrganizationAbility,
        'MotivationAbility':$scope.MotivationAbility,
        'LocationState':$scope.LocationState,
        'LocationCity':$scope.LocationCity,
        'AdditionalComment':$scope.AdditionalComment})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
         console.log("data inserted!");

    });
        $scope.FirstName= '';
        $scope.LastName= '';
        $scope.Relation= '';
        $scope.LocationState= '';
        $scope.LocationCity= '';
        $scope.AdditionalComment= '';

   }
});
myapp.controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("ajax.php")
      .success(function(data){
           $scope.data = data;
       })
       .error(function() {
       $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
       });
}]);
```

insert.php

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$FirstName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->FirstName);
$LastName = mysql_real_escape_string($data->LastName);
$Relation = mysql_real_escape_string($data->Relation);
$Recommendation = mysql_real_escape_string($data->Recommendation);
$FundManagementAbility = mysql_real_escape_string($data->FundManagementAbility);
$MentoringAbility = mysql_real_escape_string($data->MentoringAbility);
$OrganizationAbility = mysql_real_escape_string($data->OrganizationAbility);
$MotivationAbility = mysql_real_escape_string($data->MotivationAbility);
$LocationState = mysql_real_escape_string($data->LocationState);
$LocationCity = mysql_real_escape_string($data->LocationCity);
$AdditionalComment = mysql_real_escape_string($data->AdditionalComment);
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "thename", "thepassword", "programmer");
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO programmer(`FirstName`, `LastName`, `Relation`, `Recommendation`, `FundManagementAbility`, `MentoringAbility`, `OrganizationAbility`, `MotivationAbility`, `LocationState`, `LocationCity`, `AdditionalComment`)
             VALUES('".$FirstName."', '".$LastName."', '".$Relation."', '".$Recommendation."','".$FundManagementAbility."','".$MentoringAbility."','".$OrganizationAbility."','".$MotivationAbility."','".$LocationState."','".$LocationCity."','".$AdditionalComment."')");

?>
```

Comment: you can't mix MySQL APIs, and `real_escape_string()` **REQUIRES** an established connection to mysql. in other words, it's YOU who are trashing all your values and turning them into boolean falses (mysql failure), which then get turned into empty strings in your query. This should never have worked on your own server either.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first project with PHP and MYSQL. What would be the fix for this? And out of curiosity why did it work on my own Apache server.

Comment: stop using the mysql_*() function (note the **LACK** of an `i`), and learn to use prepared statements. then you won't have to worry about escaping things yourself. that and start checking return values from DB calls. don't assume success. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy usually has magic quotes on and thus `mysql_real_escape_string` might be breaking because of it, you can try to edit your `php.ini` file and modify it to the following:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = OFF
```